# PyQt: Move list item from list A to list B and the other way around

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to move selected items in QListWidget A (job_list) to QListWidget B (queue_list) and the other way around by clicking buttons for each direction.
I tried this:

```python
# Init in the top of it.
        arrow_box.addStretch(1)
        left_arrow = QPushButton('>')
        arrow_box.addWidget(left_arrow)
        right_arrow = QPushButton('<')
        arrow_box.addWidget(right_arrow)
        arrow_box.addStretch(1)        
        
        job_list = QListWidget()
        queue_list = QListWidget()

        left_arrow.clicked.connect(self.aToB(queue_list))

# Some more code here

    def aToB(self,q):
        for item in self.selectedItems():
            print(item)
            q.insertItem(10, item)
```

If I do it on this way I get the following error: *AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'selectedItems'*

I think there is a missunderstanding how to code usecases like this and I hope you can help me to find a solution. Additionally, I am glad if it promotes my understanding of PyQt.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself:

```python
class window(QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initMe()

  def initMe(self):
    #Some code here
    # The old version 
    # job_list = QListWidget()
    # queue_list = QListWidget()

   # New version:
   self.job_list = QListWidget()
   self.queue_list = QListWidget()

   #Connect method to event
   left_arrow.clicked.connect(self.atoB)
   right_arrow.clicked.connect(self.bToA)


  ## Adding the methods
  def aToB(self):
    for item in self.job_list.selectedItems():
      item = self.job_list.takeItem(self.job_list.row(item))
      self.queue_list.insertItem(self.queue_list.count() + 1, item.text())

  def bToA(self):
    for item in self.queue_list.selectedItems():
     item = self.queue_list.takeItem(self.queue_list.row(item))
     self.job_list.insertItem(self.job_list.count() + 1, item.text())
```

That works for me. Let me knwo if you have another solution or if my code can be optimized.